# python ipywidgets button clicked with CONTROL combination

Tags: python, button, ipywidgets

The typical way to create a button in python with widgets is as follows:

```
button = wd.Button(description = "Click")
output = wd.Output()
display(button, output)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    with output:
        print("button clicked")

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

when clicking the button the corresponding method runs.

Is it possible to distinguish between simply click and CTRL+click?
i.e. having like two methods,on_click, or on_CTRL_click

thanks

[image]